# How to use @track and @api at the same time

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a variable `newtags` that contains tags added by the user. When a tag is added it's shown on the interface when it's double-clicked it should disappear from the interface, for this matter I used `@track` and it works fine.

At the same time I need to set this variable by the parent component on render for this I should use `@api` but it seems like I can't use both simultaneously.

**Parent Component**

```
<template if:true={showScreen2}>
       <c-screen2 ongetgeneralinfo={handleGeneralInfo} 
                  title={title}
                  description={description}
                   newtags={newTags}>
        </c-screen2>
</template>
```

**Screen2 Component**

```
@api newtags = [];
handleTagInput(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 13){
            this.newtags = [...this.newtags, {name : event.target.value}];


         }
        }
removeTag(event){
        let tagToRemove = event.target.dataset.id;

        for(let i = 0; i < this.newtags.length; i++) {
            let obj = this.newtags[i];
            
            if(obj.name == tagToRemove){
                console.log('#');
                this.newtags.splice(i, 1);
                console.log(this.newtags);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the console:

[image]

But in the Interface, I still can see 3 tags

[image]

Comment: Don't assign values back to `@api` variable.

Comment: As a side note, I see this often; you should choose a more descriptive name than `screen2`, as it doesn't convey what the screen is, and even worse, if you have to change the order around, it can become tricky to maintain. Good variable names are a best practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot combine @track, @wire, and/or @api with each other. The child should notify the parent that it needs to remove the tag:

```
handleDoubleClick(event) {
  this.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent(
      'removetag', 
      { detail: { id: event.target.dataset.id } }
    )
  );
}
```

Which the parent then handles:

```
<!-- markup -->
onremovetag={handleRemoveTag}
```

---

```
handleRemoveTag(event) {
  this.newTags = this.newTags.filter((tag) => tag.id !== event.detail.id);
}
```

At this point, the page will refresh as you expect.

To be clear, do not attempt to modify an `@api` attribute directly, and avoid using @api get/set properties, as they are not fully reactive.